# The uncertainty principle of computer science

Tags: performance, algorithm, computer-science, turing-machines

When I work on an algorithm to solve a computing problem, I often experience that speed can be increased by using more memory, and memory usage can be decreased at the price of increased running time, *but I can never force the product of running time and consumed memory below a clearly palpable limit*. This is *formally similar* to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle: the product of the uncertainty in position and the uncertainty in momentum of a particle cannot be less than a given threshold.

Is there a theorem of computer science, which asserts the same thing? I guess it should be possible to derive something similar from the theory of Turing Machines.

Comment: You might get (better) answers from http://cs.stackexchange.com/  What do we miserable hackers know about such elevated concepts ?

Comment: The concepts are completely unrelated. The Uncertainty Principle limits the **precision** you can get in measuring physical quantities, not the **range** of values those quantities can take.

Comment: @beaker Sure they are unrelated, that's why I wrote *formal similarity* instead of *analogy*. The whole thing is just a feeling, but a very strong one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science theory rather than programming and is more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are you saying that for some problems there is a theoretical limit on the quantity (time complexity) x (space complexity), or that *all* solutions to the same problem have the same value for this product?

Comment: You can always force the sum of the complexities below the time complexity of any algorithm for the problem and below 2 to the power of the space complexity of any algorithm for the problem, but that isn't really useful because it's trivial.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus gave a positive answer here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/13664 Thank you all for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not personally familiar with a description of it that parallels Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, *per se*, but this sounds to me to be closely related to [Computational Complexity Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory). Problems can be classified according to some inherent, irreducible complexity, and I think that's what you're getting at with your limit of "the product of running time and consumed memory".

Comment: +1 I agree, the complexity of a problem may determine the limit. There is time complexity and space complexity, and what I'm thinking of is the relationship of these, which would explain the limit.